# Customise owl-carousel 2 on desktop/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Current functionality:** The carousel slider will slide using navigation dots, auto-play & the drag option in both mobile & desktop.

**New Specification:** The slider will moved to my 5th slide & stop sliding(dragable, auto-play) in mobile only, Desktop remains same.


**Current code:**

```
var sliderHome = $("#mgs-slider");
sliderHome.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    rtl: RTL,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: <?php echo $this->getStopAuto() ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
    animateOut: '<?php echo $animated['out'] ?>',
    animateIn: '<?php echo $animated['in'] ?>',
    <?php if($tpControls != 2): ?>
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"],
    <?php else:?>
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],
    <?php endif;?>
    responsive:{
        0:{
            nav: false,
            dots: true
        },
        992:{
            nav: false,
            dots: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your code

```
sliderHome.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [4, 500, true]);
// 4 is the slide index
// 500 is the speed in ms - maybe you want 0 here
```

And maybe put it inside a resize function, so it will react if the user resizes the window